# dartium (chromium) error on yaml/src/loader.dart

Tags: dart, chromium

I keep getting this

> Internal error: 'package:yaml/src/loader.dart': error: line 197 pos 32:   unexpected token '?'
>       _tryParseScalar(scalar) ?? new YamlScalar.internal(scalar.value, scalar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`??` is a quite new extension (null-aware operators) to the Dart syntax. You probably use a Dart version that doesn't support it.

Null aware operators were introduced with Dart 1.12
See https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1120
You can check your current Dart version with `dart --version` on the command line.

The package using this new feature should have a SDK constraint that limits the package version to SDK versions that support this feature.

Comment: yah, before running pub serve,

pub --version
Pub 1.12.1

weirdness it was working and seems just to affect me in my team, I can't understand the weirdness.

Comment: Weird, can you provide more information about your environment? OS version for example.

Comment: chromium Version 39.0.2171.0
OS: Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64

Comment: The Dartium version itself doesn't tell much currently but the Dart version shown in Dartium at about://version

Comment: Ahh, thanks gunter, that explains it, somehow it's not picking up my latest dart version I used brew to install both, odd
so on about:version it's showing 1.10.1  okay that explains it